# Ubuntu only Boots after Booting Windows and Restarting

Tags: dual-boot, suspend

I have been trying to get Ubuntu 16.04 to work on my computer alongside Windows 10. I followed the instructions for how to install it (I used the option to "install alongside Windows").

#### The Problem

The problem is really bizarre: When I first suspended Ubuntu and then tried to start up the computer again, it completely froze and I had to hard-reset the computer. Once I rebooted Ubuntu, it just loops forever with a blank screen and the "Ubuntu drum sound", occasionally blinking the login screen every once in a while.

#### My Attempts at Fixing it

There is one weird "fix" to this that I figured out; if I boot Windows 10, restart from there, and then choose to boot Ubuntu after the restart, then everything works smoothly. There seems to be something wrong connected to "booting the computer from after being turned off".

Another "fix" I had to do before discovering the above was to reinstall Ubuntu, in which case it works normally until I try to suspend it again.

#### My Question

Does anyone know what might be causing this? It is rather annoying to have to boot Windows, restart it and boot Ubuntu everytime I want to use it, let alone have to reinstall it.

In case this is helpful: I tried to install to Ubuntu 18.04 instead, but I receive similar problems -- the system breaks after trying to suspend, locking me at login.

Thanks in advance!

---

Here are the contents of /etc/default/grub:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Have you tried to off secure boot in BIOS settings and fast boot in windows?

Comment: I tried it now -- unfortunately it does not work :(

Comment: When you are in Ubuntu Can you open /etc/default/grub file and show the content?

Comment: Added contents of the file in the question now!

Comment: file seems OK. I think you are never shown with grub rite? Can you check in bios boot menu options if it is showing windows boot manager and Ubuntu?

Comment: When I turn on my computer, I reach the GRUB boot loader. However when I choose Ubuntu it seems to successfully load the OS, then the login screen flashes on the screen for a short second, followed by a display that eventually says "no signal" and the sweet Ubuntu drums playing in a loop for some time.

Comment: OK.. When you see the GRUB.. Can you select advanced options for Ubuntu and then the kernel lower to the present version?

Comment: Done; I tried choosing both options from a turned off computer (kernel versions 4.something.33 and 4.something.34). For the "earlier version", I received a prompt saying my graphics were not working, with a few different options like "try default graphics settings" among others. I am starting to think that there might be something wrong with my peripheral drivers, since everything seems to work when booting off of a Windows restart. I guess I should just reinstall Ubuntu for now and avoid the suspend mode. Thank you for taking time out of your day to help!

Comment: No no, don't reinstall. https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu&ved=2ahUKEwjzvuWV6b3dAhVGLo8KHU1HAa0QFjACegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw3iRKx9cHa6X1P9ekZlTOcY

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand how that link will solve my issue.

Comment: Hi, the part you attached /etc/default/grub look for 6th line containing "quite splash" change it to "nomodeset quite splash". Changing this is permanent. First to try this, when you see GRUB menu.. Select the Ubuntu and press e to edit the options to add this text "nomodeset"

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQRZq.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NcRJ.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvVrX.jpg
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pr7fv.jpg

Comment: what is your graphics card?

Comment: My graphics card is a GTX 1070! Aha, I see what you mean! I will try this :)

Comment: i think you dont have drivers installed for your graphics card. once you enter ubuntu. install the drivers. https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked. You were completely right about the graphics hardware not being compatible with configuration directly from kernel :) the nomodeset worked wonders! Now I can suspend, boot from startup and everything! If you would like to formulate an answer I would be happy to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your graphics card might be causing this.

try to enter into ubuntu with "nomodeset"

1. when you see the grub, highlight to "Ubuntu" and press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the kernal parameters.
2. go to the line starting with "linux" and find the string `ro quiet splash`
3. add the text `nomodeset` in between "ro quiet splash". now it should look like this `ro nomodeset quiet splash`
4. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.
5. Once you enter into Ubuntu.. try to install the rite drivers for your graphics card.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This worked, but instead of the last step I simply added nomodeset to the string you mentioned in /etc/default/grub and performed sudo update-grub :) thanks!

Comment: Oh, ok, thats good. some times, booting with `nomodeset` will make lower resolutions. if you are satisfied after step 4. changing the values permenant via /etc/default/grub is a good idea.