# Changing from Nvidia to Nouveau causes hang at boot

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, gdm, nouveau

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. I was running Nouveau and everything was fine, but in order to run Android Studio and emulate an Android device, I needed to install the Nvidia driver. I used the `Software & Updates` -> `Additional Drivers`, selected the `NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-390 (proprietary, tested)` and applied the changes.

The driver works fine but it enforces a maximum resolution that is lower than what I use with Nouveau, so I decided to switch back after finishing with Android Studio.

I switched back to Nouveau using the same `Software & Updates` -> `Additional Drivers` process. Now when I boot, my machine hangs and never reaches the sign in screen.

#### TL;DR

- Nouveau was working fine.
- Switched to Nvidia using the `Software & Updates` GUI.
- Used for a few days (including reboot/shutdown).
- Switched back to Nouveau using the same GUI.
- Boot now hangs and doesn't reach the sign in screen.

#### Errors at startup

```
[FAILED] Failed to start User Manager for UID 121.
See 'systemctl status user@121.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Removed slice User Slice of gdm.
[  OK  ] Created slice User Slice of gdm.
... (repeated messages)
[  OK  ] Started Session c15 of user gdm.
[  OK  ] Removed slice User Slice of gdm.
[  OK  ] Created slice User Slice of gdm.
[FAILED] Failed to start User Manager for UID 121.
See 'systemctl status user@121.service' for details.
... (repeated messages)
```

```
$ systemctl status user@121.service
* user@121.service - User Manager for UID 121
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/user@.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
 Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/user@.service.d
          |-timeout.conf
 Active: inactive (dead)
```

#### Current workaround (after multiple attempts)

- I boot by using `nomodeset` as per [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075544/ubuntu-only-boots-after-booting-windows-and-restarting/1075682#1075682).
- Switch to Nvidia using the `Software & Updates` GUI.
- Reboot to default Ubuntu install (works fine).
- Switch to Nouveau using the `Software & Updates` GUI.
- Reboot to default Ubuntu install (works fine).
- Change resolution with xrandr.
- Works until I do a full shutdown/startup.

I've seen solutions elsewhere, but they're either outdated or don't work. Can anyone advise how I can switch back to Nouveau without these problems?

### Edit 1

I've tried adding `nomodeset` as per [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075544/ubuntu-only-boots-after-booting-windows-and-restarting/1075682#1075682).

- I can get into Ubuntu.
- Screen resolution is very low.
- Can't change resolution as per [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution) because `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default`.

Comment: Have you tried with `nomodeset` while booting?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have not tried this. I'm relatively new to Ubuntu/Linux as a desktop - could you give me a bit more detail on how to try this?

Comment: please go through this Q&A https://askubuntu.com/a/1075682/739431

Comment: Thanks for your help @PRATAP. I can get into Ubuntu but the resolution is far too low. See my question edit.

Comment: ya, `nomodeset` will give a chance to at least enter into Ubuntu. you need to install the rite drivers for your graphics card. or try to uninstall all the previously installed drivers and see.

Comment: The `nouveau` driver works fine, when I can boot into Ubuntu. The problem started happening after switching from `Nvidia` back to `nouveau`. So I feel the problem is where the `Nvidia` install has messed up some configuration files somewhere... but I don't know where.

Comment: When you switched from Nvidia to nouveau have you Uninstalled Nvidia drivers?

Comment: I used the `Software & Updates` GUI to switch from `Nvidia` to `nouveau`, so I don't know. I suspect that the Nvidia driver is still installed, but not used.

Comment: What is your graphic card model?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/206289/739431 please go through this answer.

Comment: The card is GeForce GTX 750 Ti. Thanks for your suggestion. I followed that answer and was able to boot without problems this morning. I will wait for a few days to make sure it is working! :)

Comment: good idea @Tom.